# error request for member .. in .. which is of non-class type - C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, struct, compiler-errors, c-strings

I have got this error: "error: request for member 'nume' in 'tablou[j]', which is of non-class type ' [100]'", and I don't really know how to solve it.I tried searching on youtube and google but I found nothing .Does anyone have any ideas for how to solve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct{
    int counter;
    char nume[20] = " ";
}tablou[10][100];

int main()
{
    int n, counter = 0;
    char second[10][100];
    bool verify = true;

    cout<<"Cate nume?";
    cin>>n;

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin.getline(second[i],20);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        verify = true;

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(second[i], tablou[j].nume) == 0)
            {
                verify = false;
            }
        }

        if(verify == true)
        {
            strcpy(tablou[i].nume, second[i]);

            for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                if(strcmp(tablou[i].nume, second[k]))
                {
                    tablou[i].counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout<<tablou[i].nume<<" "<<tablou[i].counter<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tablou[10][100]` is defined with two dimentsions, but `tablou[j].nume` only uses one of them. Technically `tablou[j]` is a one dimentional array.

Comment: I think you might need `struct{ int counter; char nume[20] = " "; }tablou[10];`

Answer (score 0):

tablou is a 2d array

```
struct{
    int counter;
    char nume[20] = " ";
}tablou[10][100];
```

its elements are `tablou[x][y]`

you try to access an element with only one index

```
if(strcmp(second[i], tablou[j].nume) == 0)
----------------------------^
```

I do not know what your code is trying to do , but thats why you get the error

Answer (score 0):

The array `tablou` is a two-dimensopnal array

```
struct{
    int counter;
    char nume[20] = " ";
}tablou[10][100];
```

So for example the expression `tablou[j]` has the array type the_unnamed_structure[100].

So such an expression like this

```
tablou[j].nume
```

is incorrect and the compiler issues an error.

Maybe actually you mean the following declaration of the array

```
struct{
    int counter;
    char nume[20] = " ";
}tablou[10];
```

Also in these loops

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    verify = true;

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(second[i], tablou[j].nume) == 0)
        {
            verify = false;
        }
    }

    if(verify == true)
    {
        strcpy(tablou[i].nume, second[i]);

        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            if(strcmp(tablou[i].nume, second[k]))
            {
                tablou[i].counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

some elements of the array `tablou` can be skipped if `verify` is set to `false` because you are using the index `i` to assign elements of the array  `tablou`. That is the number of actual elements of the array `tablou` can be less than `n`. In this case this for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    cout<<tablou[i].nume<<" "<<tablou[i].counter<<endl;
}
```

will invoke undefined behavior because the data member `counter` will be uninitialized for some outputted elements of the array.

You need to support a separate variable as an index in the array  `tablou`.

Comment: I am trying to assign to the 2d array a name on each line, and I used the same code when I am assigning values to the 2d array named second. 

for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin.getline(second[i],20);
    }

Why does it work here and not when I try assigning values to the other 2d array?

Comment: @AndreiMiroiu The array of structures contains the data member nume that in turn is an array. In fact you have a two-dimensional character array. So if to declare the array of structures as a two-dimensional array you will get in fact a three-dimensional character array.